# Using Ascii Code for left quote in regex

Tags: .net, regex

To start, here's the current tool I use to test my regex: http://www.myregextester.com/index.php

Here is my test string: `Test “,”," Data`

There is a left quote, right quote and straight quote.

I'm trying to craft a regex that ensures the given string does not contain a left quote. I've been trying to use the ascii code for left quote, but it's not working : 
`^[^\x93]+$`

I've been able to use ascii codes for specific letters and the regex works as expected; however, I cannot use the ascii code for left quotes. Why not?

Comment: You don't need to use the codes. It should work with the actual characters `^[^“]+$`. Or do you have any reason why you want to use them as codes?

Comment: That's the wrong code.  http://codepoints.net/U+93 http://codepoints.net/U+201C

Comment: I wouldn't use a literal Unicode in any regular expression. I'd use its codepoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex ascii code for left quote is:

```
[\x{201C}]
```

my regex example: http://regex101.com/r/pY9uF1

For .net specifically, it would be:

```
[\u201C]
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/gB6lN1

So in .net for example, you could test if the string contains left quote, something like this:

```
string pattern = @"[\u201C]";
string input = 'Test “,”," Data';
Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (m.Success)
   Console.WriteLine("The string contains a left quote!");
```